# Atom can't recognize Python scripts

Tags: python, atom-editor

Hello everyone and thanks for reading. Today I tried to open a python script with Atom but it doesn't recognize that it is written in Python. Also even if a make a new script and save it as .py the problem insists. Not recognizing it as python script doesn't allow Atom to change colors of fonts or suggest words when programming etc, but I can still run the script normally through cmd.. Atom just displays it as plain text. What is even more weird is that when I click the button (bottom right of Atom's IDE) which opens up the available language formats, I can see everything (Auto Detection, Plain Text, Java, C, ...) other than Python.. [Atom IDE can't find python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXRIU.png)

I run Windows 10 64bit, I have python 3.6.3 (checked the path already and seems it is working since I can see the version through cmd), I have also downloaded pip, sklearn

Now for Atom, I have only installed 3 packages, which are all for running scripts through Atom (atom-runner, platform-ide-terminal, script). I have already reinstalled both Atom & Python. Note that I also have version 2 python in my computer, but haven't linked a path to my laptop's systems variables so I guess it is not an issue.

I would really appreciate any suggestions, I am stuck here 1 day now and I don't want to switch Atom for anything else.

Comment: What does executing `apm list --enabled | grep language-python` in a terminal return?

Comment: Sorry, just saw that you are on Windows. But you can also look through the output of `apm list --enabled` manually to check if the `language-python` package ist listed.

Comment: It doesnt print Python... How is that possible? When I type: "Python" I get:
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov  8 2017, 15:10:56) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

Comment: It has nothing to do with Python itself. The `language-python` Atom package does the syntax highlighting and some other things in Atom. It's a core package, so it should be installed by default. Can you try `apm enable language-python`?

Comment: THANK YOU! It worked, Atom instantly recognized the python script. Also thanks for sharing your knowledge of the language-x... i thought it would be the same as Python itself.

Comment: I think that what went wrong is this: Yesterday, I manually deleted some packages of Atom (manually deleted the folders into "packages" that were created an hour ago) It seems that I deleted more than I should. Or else I can't find another logical explanation

Comment: That is a likely explanation then.

Answer (score -1):

"It has nothing to do with Python itself. The language-python Atom package does the syntax highlighting and some other things in Atom. It's a core package, so it should be installed by default. Can you try apm enable language-python?" from user: anothernode

This solved my issued